# How to access a input based on the label text via xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to access the input field based on the label text as below. but I'm unable to access the input field.

HTML:

```
 <div>
     <label>Email</label>
     <input .......>
 </div>
```

Xpath that I used:

```
 //*[contains(., 'Email')]/input
```

By giving the xpath **//*[contains(., 'Email')]** I can able to get the label element. But after appending the **/input**, unable to access the input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath` to get required `input`:

```
//div[label='Email']/input
```